# Back end process in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I have created a simple web app to Import data from excel to database. Excel sheet has millions of records if i Transfer these records then it takes time 10 to 15 minutes. But I want to create back end process which will never kill till complete.

Please suggest me solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

MSDN has some articles on [Asynchronous Programming Design Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx), which describes some methods to accomplish this is C# 4.0+. The new [Parallel features (Await/Task)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057359/new-c-await-feature) in C# 5.0+ are something to keep up to date on as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate service (or program if that's easier for you) that checks for a new file every few seconds.