# What are examples of dependent work that will prevent async-await from having any benefit?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await

Quick question about `async`-`await`.

If I have a chunk of code like

```
object foo; 
Task t1 = LongRunningTaskThatSetsFoo(out foo); 
UseFooToDoSomething(foo);
await t1;
```

then what will happen? Because there isn't any independent work to be done between the time when `LongRunningTaskThatSetsFoo` is allowed to start (line 2) and the time when we wait for its result (line 4).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the new C# await feature do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057359/whats-the-new-c-sharp-await-feature-do)

Comment: Marked as potential duplicate as question title and "then what will happen?" are possibly at odds and the question is more about the internals. async / await always usually has a benefit as it allows the thread to return to the pool and process other things that are going on.

Comment: You can't have an `async` method with an `out` parameter. If `LongRunningTaskThatSetsFoo` is not `async`, it will have set `Foo` when it returns.

Comment: @Dennis_E Technically it could be a non-async method that just returns a `Task`, but even so, it's probably just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What will happen?  `LongRunningTaskThatSetsFoo` isn't allowed to return the `Task` until it has set `foo`, meaning it has to provide `foo` when *starting* the asynchronous operation, and not when the asynchronous operation *ends*.  This *probably* just doesn't make sense.  I suppose technically you could include information about what `LongRunningTaskThatSetsFoo` is *going* to do, rather than what it has done, but I'm...skeptical.

Anyway, since `foo` has to have been set before the asyncrhonous operation would be allowed to *start* (which is when `LongRunningTaskThatSetsFoo` returns) `UseFooToDoSomething` will then use `foo`, *then* the method will return and execution will continue after the *`Task`* returned by `LongRunningTaskThatSetsFoo` completes.

You almost certainly don't want to do this.  If `LongRunningTaskThatSetsFoo` produces a value, then it should return a `Task<T>` where `foo` is the result of that `Task<T>`.  Of course, asynchronous operations that produce a result aren't in any way useless.  They're *quite* useful.   The current thread wouldn't be able to do any work that depended on the result, but they'd be able to perform operations that *didn't* depend on the result, and let the operations that *did* depend on the result start running as soon as the result is computed.